# Windows Protect Strorage Service store private key's cipher text?

Tags: ntfs

I'm reading [NTFS file encryption explanation from ntfs.com](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-encrypted.htm), and I think I have understood it quite well, except a baffle with [a statement](http://www.ntfs.com/issues-encrypted-files.htm):

> Protected Storage encrypts all private keys with **Session Key**, derived from 512 bit Master Key, and stores them in `%UserProfile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\User SID` .
>
> ...
>
> The overall security could be significantly enhanced by encrypting private keys with System Key. The syskey.exe utility can be used to store System Key on a floppy disk and remove it from computer.

I interpret the first half sentence as this: **Windows does not store private keys's plain text, but store their cipher text, through some cipher algorithm with Session Key as the encryption key.**

### Then I have two questions.

One, is that cipher algorithm symmetric or asymmetric?

Two, whose private keys? I don't think it's a normal user's EFS certificate private key, then whose?

As far as I know, normal user's EFS private key is calculated from the very user's password hash and a pre-stored EFS-certificate-associated cipher text(please name it), which is not related to the **Session Key**.